# Битрикс , как убрать ссылку "Возврат к списку" из странице детальной новости?

Tags: битрикс

Битрикс , как убрать ссылку "Возврат к списку" из странице детальной новости?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно отредактировать комплексный шаблон `bitrix:news`, который используется для этой страницы, а именно его файл `detail.php`. Ссылка, которую нужно удалить находится в этом файле после кода подключения шаблона вывода детальной страницы `bitrix:news.detail` и имеет примерно такой вид:

```
<p><a href="<?=$arResult["FOLDER"].$arResult["URL_TEMPLATES"]["news"]?>"><?=GetMessage("T_NEWS_DETAIL_BACK")?></a></p>
```

Comment: спасибо , получилось)